# Add node to xml without simplexml or domdocument

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument

My php version is 5.1.2 and I don't have access to simplexml's addChild function or ANY DomDocument stuff. Any ideas on how I can add a node in an xml file?

For example:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<post>
<title>cool website</title>
<email>victor.chen@fake.com</email>
<first>Victor</first>
<last>Chen</last>
<date>01/04/13</date>
<time>12:31 am</time>
<category>acm</category>
<content>gj</content>
</post>
```

I would like to add another node like above. What is the best way given my limitations?

Comment: Do you have *any* of the other XML extensions installed?

Comment: I can use almost all of simplexml's functions except for the addchild. I'm not sure what other xml extensions are installed

Comment: Check `phpinfo` for the installed extension list?

Comment: Not sure what some of these are but it saids: libxml 2.6.23, pcre, reflection, simplexml, spl, xml libxml2 2.6.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [`XMLReader`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) and [`XMLWriter`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) are available:

1. Use an `XMLReader` object to copy everything over to a paired `XMLWriter` object *until* the point where you want to add the node.
2. Add whatever nodes you want using the `XMLWriter` object.
3. Continue copying until the end of the document.

XMLReader and XMLWriter were added to PHP by default as of 5.1.2, but it's still possible they were disabled via compile-time flags.

If not even these are available, you need to use an [`XMLParser`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) and write out the XML (the `XMLWriter` part) very carefully yourself. The only thing I know for sure that you have based on your phpinfo is the XML parser.

You *really* need to upgrade your PHP.